# How to shrink the size of an Azure Cloud image from cloud-images.ubuntu.com?

Tags: partitioning, virtualization, cloud, hyper-v, azure

I'm currently setting up a dynamic High-Performance-Computing cluster in Azure, and I'm thinking of basing it on Ubuntu.

The Microsoft documentation recommends to base an Ubuntu image on the tested Ubuntu Cloud-Images for Azure (e.g., https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/bionic/current/bionic-server-cloudimg-amd64-azure.vhd.zip)

The issue is, that these images are already 30GB is size, even if only a fraction of the space is actually used. In order to speed-up the deployment time of my cluster nodes in Azure, I would like to have a smaller image (e.g., 10GB).

What would be the most efficient way, to shrink the size of the above mentioned image? Is there any way efficient way, or do I have to create a smaller image from scratch?

I would be totally happy if somebody could help me out with this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can't shrink managed disks in Azure directly. However, you can use another VM (or on your computer) to handle the image: download, shrink, upload to your Storage account as Block blob, then create an image.

**Using Hyper-V:**

- Create/use a VM with Linux (preferably with GUI)
- Attach the image you will use
- Shrink the last partition to lees than the desired size (9 GB for example) (fsck before)
- Poweroff the VM and detack the disk
- Shrink the disk (either using qemu-img or the Hyper-V disk utility), ensuring,

  - The resulting image is (much) greater than the end of the last partition)
  - It is allocated to a megabyte(*)
- Attach the disk image again
- Boot the VM
- Rellocate the backup GPT to the end of the disk (using `gdisk` or `sgdisk`)
- Run `fsck`
- Poweroff the VM
- Detach the disk, then, swap it with the disk image used for handling the new disk
- Ensure the disk image boots on Hyper-V
- The image is ready to upload to your storage account and to be used to create a managed image
- Finally, ensure the image disk boots in Azure

(*)Please notice that, in order to import a managed disk from a Block blob (if you want to handle the image from the local computer, then, uploading to your Storage account), the image **should** be allocated to MB, and the image must be in VHD fixed. Otherwise, the import will fail. Some tools like qemu-img (and even the Hyper-V disk utility) adds extra padding of 512 bytes to the end of the resulted image.

**Another (quick-and-dirty) approach is using Azure:**

- Create a VM (preferably Ubuntu 18.04)

  - Attach an empty managed disk of the desired size
- Download and the image
- Install `qemu-utils`
- Convert the image to RAW

  - `qemu-img convert -f vpc -O raw bionic.vhd bionic.img`
- Import the downloaded image as loop device

  - `sudo losetup -f bionic.img`
- Shrink the last partition to 9 GiB using parted (`fsck` before)
- Detach the image to the loop device

  - `sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0`
- Copy the image to the attached managed disk using `dd` (quick-and-dirty)

  - `dd if /dev/loop0 of=/dev/sdb bs=4096`
- Rellocate the backup GPT to the end of the disk (using `gdisk` or `sgdisk`)
- Grow the last partition to the end of the disk
- Run `fsck`
- Stop (dellocate) the VM
- Detach the recently filled disk
- Swap the boot disk with the recently created one
- Start the VM with the recently created disk to ensure it boots
- Do anything to prepare the image
- If everything goes well, [capture the VM into a managed image](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/capture-image)

Finally, NEVER, ever truncate an image without shinking the last partition first! Otherwise, the image is lost (or at least hard to recovery; is better to start over).